# 5 unit vectors with sum 0 and with rational angles

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Is there a 'non-trivial' example of $5$ unit vectors in the plane, such that their sum is $0$ and such that the angle between any $2$ of them is a rational multiple of $\pi$? By non-trivial I mean that they don't form the vertices of a regular $5$-gon, and no $2$ of the vectors sum to $0$.

If the answer is no, what is the smallest replacement of $5$ (with an 'suitable' extension of the non-triviality condition)? One can do it for $7$ (using the fact that the $15$th cyclotomic polynomial has $7$ non-zero coefficients), but even that configuration has a symmetry, so perhaps it's not sufficiently non-trivial (see the picture).

[image]

Comment: If $n\ge 6$, can any five of the n-th roots of unity form the five vectors satisfying your need?

Comment: @Lai if those 5 roots of unity sum up to $0$ (and no 2 of them sum up to $0$ etc) then yes

Comment: Yes, it is really difficult!